# Which quantity is independent of others?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

My [textbook](http://www.ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/leph105.pdf) quotes that:pg.no-190

> The three quantities $X,\, U_r$ and $U$ are interrelated and only one of them is independent. Given one, the other two may be easily determined.
>
> Where
>
> - $X$=magnetic susceptibility
> - $U_r$=relative magnetic permeability
> - $U$=magnetic permeability of substance.

## My attempt:

$U$ depends on $U_r$ and $U_o$ so it can't be independent. If I assume $X$ is independent then it would lead that $U_r$ is also independent since $1+X=U_r.$ Since 1 is constant. But only one has to be independent. So which one?

Comment: Hint: And, Ur=U/Uo where Uo is the permeability of free space.

Comment: @Benjamin   So it implies that Uo is independent but Uo is not mentioned

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a substance/medium is *specified*, its *magnetic permeability* is *known*. Having a knowledge of this magnetic permeability, the *relative magnetic permeability* of the substance (with respect to that of the free space) *can be* calculated.  Knowing this ratio, further, will enable you to calculate the *magnetic susceptibility* as mentioned by the formula in your question. So, as you can see, the *only* independent physical quantity (which *only* depends on the *nature* of a substance) is its *magnetic permeability* to begin with. So, this is the quantity known as an "independent."